# Stack Overflow Data Dump Import questions

Tags: support, data-dump

I have downloaded the data dump torrents

I have a folder called 012011 Web Applications (it has comments.xml, badges.xml, posts.xml, users.xml, votes.xml) and the database I created is called Stack Exchange. What tables should I create in this database? Should create one that is called Web Applications.Badges, WebApplications.Posts.. etc..etc?

I am just confused on the formatting issues.

Comment: Read [this document](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-data-explorer) first, then have a look in [these search results](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=[data-dump]+import).

Comment: I followed the thing but then SkySander's tool won't run

Answer (score 1):

You can import your data into a relational database using the following importer:

https://github.com/1123/StackExchangeImporter

This importer will create the database schema for you, and populate the tables.